# How to solve this integral which has a root over the quadratic polynomial divided by another quadratic polynomial?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, quadratics

Can anyone help me solve this integral? I have the value of $b$ (real and positive, most probably lower than $5$) and using the value of integral, I have to calculate $a$.

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1+ax^2}{1+bx^2}}\,dx.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to know what $b$ is in the original problem, since in full generality

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1+ax^2}{1+bx^2}}\,dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{b}}\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{b}x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\int_{0}^{\log(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{b+1})}\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{b}\sinh^2 x}\,dx$$
is just an [incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind).

You are looking for the inverse function of a highly non-elementary function. However, the last function, as a function of $a$, behaves like $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$, so the problem is well suited for the application of a numerical method: [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method). If $K$ is the given value for the integral, take $a_0$ as $K^2 b$ and

$$ a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{K-\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1+a_n x^2}{1+b x^2}}\,dx}{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2\,dx}{2\sqrt{(1+a_n x^2)(1+b x^2)}}}.$$
With few iterations, $a_n$ will be an excellent approximation for the wanted $a$. Obviously, you have to compute two incomplete elliptic integrals at every step: choose any quadrature algorithm you like for such a task, that integrand functions are very well-behaved. The state of art is to use the [arithmetic-geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean), as mentioned by the Wikipedia page about [elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Comment: Hi! I have edited the question. 'b' real and positive and not very large. Does this help?

Comment: @ShreyanshRatnamKhare: no.

Comment: Sorry! That is all I know about 'b'. Can you tell me what you need to know? I might be missing your point...

Comment: How can I solve the integration by Newton's Method? Or are you referring to the [Newton-Cotes Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cotes_formulas)?

Comment: @ShreyanshRatnamKhare: I am referring to Newton's method. You are looking for the solution of $f(a)=K$, where $K$ is the given value for the integral and $f(a)$ is the integral as a function of $a$. You may compute $f'$ through the fundamental theorem of calculus ($f'$ is just another integral depending on $a$) and since you know in advance that $f(a)\approx\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$, the wanted $a$ will be close to $K^2 b$. Use that point as a starting point for Newton's method.

Comment: Thanks! I know how the Newton's method works but the integral still gives me elliptic function according to Wolfram Alpha. Matlab is unable to deal with an integral like this. I'll just have to read up on elliptic integrals, it seems. Can you please tell how you reached the last function? What substitution did you use?

Comment: @ShreyanshRatnamKhare: it is just differentiation under the integral sign, since $$\frac{d}{da}\sqrt{\frac{1+ax^2}{1+bx^2}}=\frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{(1+ax^2)(1+bx^2)}}.$$ Then I just applied the usual Newton's iteration for finding the root of $f-K$:  $$ x\mapsto x-\frac{f(x)-K}{f'(x)}.$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but why are we differentiating by 'a' when the integral is over 'x'? Can you just fill in the missing steps please?

Comment: Anyway, I think I spent enough time on providing you a clear enough answer, try to work about it by yourself.

Comment: I still don't understand how you reached sinh(x)^2 from this but thanks anyways.